# Attribute Routing and Error pages in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a website, it uses attibute routing.

I have this in web.config:

```
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound" />
    </customErrors>
```

I have an errorcontroller that looks like this

```
[RoutePrefix("error")]
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    [Route("internalserver")]
    public ActionResult InternalServer()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Route( "notfound" )]
    public ActionResult NotFound() {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Nothing is being caught when I have 404's or 500's. I have no HandleErrorAttribute nor any other mechanism for handling http errors in my code.

My head hurts now, so any help would be much appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: Are you testing in localhost or live?

Comment: localhost in the moment

Comment: try to upload on server. I had a same problem. but once I uploaded on server it is working all fine

Comment: You could instead use `<customErrors mode="Off" />` then handle all errors in your application using `global.asax` and `protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)` - you can redirect to an error page from here *or* return an error object for AjaxRequests

Comment: yeah, I did that as well. Much easier...